# How to modify a WSP file (convert .cab to .wsp)

Tags: 2013, development, site-template, solution-package, wspbuilder

I want to do some modifications to a site template, mainly to set its master page , same as mentioned here [link](http://jeffreypaarhuis.com/2011/10/21/your-master-page-automatically-on-newly-created-subsites/)

so i did the following stpes:-

1. i save a site as template.
2. i went to "Site Settings">>"Solutions".
3. i download the .wsp file representing the site template.
4. i rename the .wsp to .cab
5. using a tool named ACDZip i open the .cab , edit the .xml file.
6. save the file inside the .cab

now i am not sure how i can convert the .cab to .wsp file again? so i can upload my .wsp site template again inside the solutions ??
i tried rename the .cab to .wsp but seems this steps will modify the name not the extension !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can (also) use **Visual Studio** to Import and modify your WSP.

Have a look at this link from Microsoft (For 2010 but still working for 2013): [Importing the .wsp File](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231603.aspx#Anchor_3)

in few step :

1. Create a VS project from type : Import SharePoint Solution Package
2. Choose your WSP (after it will create the SharePoint project with all files/elements of you wsp
3. make your change is the solution
4. Package and Deploy your new solution

Comment: so in this way i do not have to create .cab file is this correct? i will be working with the .wsp directly?

Comment: yes, you don't create a cab file. With this solution you don't modify the WSP source, you will generate a copy ;)

Comment: now i did the steps , where inside the visual studio i modify the .xml file i want . then rebuild>>publish. then i upload the new .wsp file inside the solutions.. but the Activate button for the wsp will be disabled .. not sure why this is happening

Comment: Yes you just deployed a new solution, by default all feature (Activate button) of your solution are disable. You, need to manually enable (Active) this feature with SharePoint UI or PowerShell .....

Answer (score 1):

You can do that from PowerShell. For that purpose you need small but extremely helpful library called 'CabLib'. It's included as part of the wspbuilder (old tool to build and pack projects for SharePoint 2007).
You need to download `CabLib.dll` from here - [WSPBuilder Extensions 1.0.6](http://wspbuilder.codeplex.com/releases/view/30858). Under the downloads select "*CabLib.dll for x64 systems (version: 10.5)*"

Now follow this steps:

1. Create a folder, say `testing`, in that folder put `CabLib.dll` and your `.wsp` file.
2. Create new PowerShell script in that folder, called say `pack.ps1`.
3. Put following inside your `pack.ps1`:

```ps
$currentDir = Split-Path -Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path -Parent

# LOAD CABLIB LIBRARY TO EXTRACT/COMPRESS .WSP FILES
[void][reflection.assembly]::LoadFile("$currentDir\CabLib.dll")

function Extract-Directory ( $cabFileFullPathAndFilename, $dir){
    $c = new-object CabLib.Extract
    $c.ExtractFile($cabFileFullPathAndFilename, $dir)
}

function Compress-Directory ($dir, $cabFileFullPathAndFilename){
    write $dir
    $c = new-object CabLib.Compress 
    $c.CompressFolder($dir, $cabFileFullPathAndFilename, $null, $null, $null, 0) 
}

function DoWork($action) {

    $file = "<your wsp template name>.wsp"
    $file = Get-ChildItem $file
    $fileDir = $file.Directory
    $fileName = $file.Name
    $tempFolder = "$currentdir\extracted"
    $newFile = "$fileDir\Updated-$fileName"

    if($action -eq "extract") {
        Write-Host "Extracting...."
        Extract-Directory $file $tempFolder 
        return;
    }

    if($action -eq "compress") {
        Write-Host "Compressing...."
        if((Test-Path $newFile) -ne $True) { New-Item $newFile -type file | Out-Null }

        Compress-Directory $tempFolder $newFile

        Write-Host "Cleaning Up...."
        Remove-Item $tempFolder -recurse
        return;
    }
}

DoWork($args[0])
```

4. Inside script update `$file` variable to point to your actual `.wsp`.
5. Open Powershell in your newly created folder `testing`.
6. Run `.\pack.ps1 "extract"`. New folder `testing\extracted` will be created with content of your `.wsp`.
7. Inside this folder perform required updates to xml files, etc.
8. From Powershell run `.\pack.ps1 "compress"`. Folder will deleted and new file `Update-<your template>.wsp` will be created with content from "extracted" folder

Comment: thanks for the reply,, but seems this is a lot of work,, is there any tool that can help me in doing so ?tnx

Comment: I'm not aware about such tool (GUI). In the past I used only command-line tools like Makecab or PowerShell. You can setup the script once and then reuse for other templates. Actually not so many work.

Comment: I see that `ACDZip` allows compression. DId you try to make .wsp again with `ACDZip`?

Comment: now as mentioned on the other reply.. i download the .wsp from the sharepoint solutions, then using VS2012 i created a new project and i was able to access the .wsp file directly inside the Vs. where i did my modifications, build>>publish the solution.. then i upload the new .wsp file inside sharepoint ,,but the problem is that the activate button was disabled,, so i am unable to activate the wsp to be able to use the site template